# Multiple File Upload ISsue in IE

Tags: file, upload

Hi the following Statement for uploading Multiple files by holding  shift and control key "input type="file" name="uploadFile" size="60" multiple="multiple"" was not working in IE.Please help

Answer (score 0):

Replace the leading quotation with <, and the trailing quotation with /> as seen below.

```
  <input type="file" name="uploadFile" multiple="multiple" size="60" />
```

Note: The multiple attribute of the  tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions. I believe it is for HTML5 enabled browsers.

Edit: Just updated IE to version 10, multiple file select working fine now.